# How to return list of items from an array given list on indices in numpy

Tags: numpy

I have an array `arr` and a list of indices that I want to get `indices`. I want to get subset of array corresponding to items in `indices` and the complement of that.

For example

for

```
arr = np.asarray([2, 4, 1, 5, 6])
indices = np.asarray([2, 4])
```

I would get

```
[1, 6] and [2, 4, 5]
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok, I give up. Where does the `[2, 4, 5]` come from in your result?

Comment: it is a complement . you return items given by indices and delete these items from an original array (or it can be any there way of giving complement

Comment: is your `arr` a numpy array? If so, please edit your code accordingly

Comment: @Mstaino edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `np.isin` or `np.in1d` (using masks):

```
arr = np.asarray([2, 4, 1, 5, 6])
indices = np.asarray([2, 4])
m = np.in1d(np.arange(len(arr)), indices)
arr1, arr2 = arr[m], arr[~m]
arr1, arr2
>>array([1, 6]), array([2, 4, 5])
```

Alternatively, using `np.setdiff1d` for the complementary part (can be faster for larger arrays and indices):

```
arr1 = arr[indices]
arr2 = arr[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(arr)), indices, True)]
```